# Rails + Omniauth: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to use the Spotify API to sign up/in a user via Devise but I'm getting:

`undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass`

in:

**pages_controller.rb**

`@spotify_user = RSpotify::User.new(request.env['omniauth.auth'])`

===

Here's my stack:

**home.html.erb**

```
<li><%= link_to 'Sign in with Spotify', user_spotify_omniauth_authorize_path %></li>
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'callbacks' }
```

**callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class CallbacksController <  Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  def spotify
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end
end
```

**initializers/devise.rb**

```
  RSpotify.authenticate(ENV["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"])
  config.omniauth :spotify, ENV["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"], scope: 'user-read-email playlist-modify-public user-library-read user-library-modify'
```

Comment: you said you `puts` but from when and where are you doing it?  How /where are your environment variables defined?  Are you sure also `ENV['SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET']` is defined ?

Comment: the puts is in the initializer `puts ENV["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"]` brings back the correct key from `config/env.yml`

Comment: Updated with a bit more detail on the error